# Special twist to make pasta noodles like the ones at Take Aways / Kebap Huts

Tags: noodles

You people out there are my last hope for finding my holy grail.
I have tried dozens and dozens of recipes - none of them came even close to what I am searching.

I look for a way to make noodles like they sell on Kebap Huts, Asia Take Aways and many
other shops. Not the slimy spongy likes - I have lots of recipes for them and can cook them
to perfection. Even the hand pulled ones.
No.
I look for the classic noodles, squared, about 2 x 2mm to 3 x 3 mm. Color like normal
classic italian pasta - but taste much softer and the surface will absorb sauces very nicely - which is important as they are fried in pans or on grills.
Squared seems to be important as they are done with a classic pasta machine where you roll the dough
and not press it through a hole - or even pull them.
I even thought it might be potatoe starch in there, cause the noodles have that fleshy soft kind
of touch. But at least the way I tried it was definitely the wrong one.
Lye water, baked baking soda - all kinds of flour. I tried so many things, I even can't remember all
I tried.

And yes, I looked on Google and not only there - does not bring me a milimeter closer to my goal.

There are no recipes except for the classic Asian Noodles - which are **NOT** what I am looking for.
I think it must be a special twist with the flour, or an ingredient I have not even thought of.

[image]

Comment: Welcome and +1. Not an answer but I have had the noodles you're referring to from a local (VA, US) Chinese takeout. I absolutely love them! I have had no luck finding a name, recipe, or pre-made (dried or fresh) to buy. Searching for any type of square noodles has proved unsuccessful. I do think they are a wheat noodle but, other than that, I have no info. Hope we see some good answers to your question.

Comment: I hope so too. I agree with wheat - and always thought that it has to be the classic flour . But lately I saw a book about food textures , and there was a small indication that maybe part of my missing recipe or ingredient could be full grain flour. As with color and a strange feeling in my belly I also thought it could be spelt . But I tried it once and it did not come close. And all the chinese in my region by it from one company , which is not talking about how to do them.

Comment: Have you asked any of the restaurant where you ate these noodles about the name?

Comment: the Kebap selling people dont have any name for it but noodles . And the asian restaurants also dont have special names for it . One chinese once said to me that these are Hokkien Noodles - but they also only buy it premade . Even if they are Hokkien Noodles - there is NO recipe around the world wide web that I could find. Not even in asian cookbooks , of which I have plenty . I own 5 books only about asian noodles and their recipes - but nowhere the thick square frying noodles that you can buy everywhere around.

Comment: It would be good to have a picture of the noodles, I'm not sure what's being asked.

Comment: [Picture of the noodles](https://i.ibb.co/XSrgW40/Noodle.jpg)

Comment: Hope the link works :-)

Comment: Picture is firewalled for me, but is what you are looking for a hand pulled noodle, namely a Shaanxi style, sometimes called a Hong Kong noodle.  Normally thin, roundish and often is twisted bundles?  If so, the key is a base in the noodle which causes slightly different texture.  There is also a Beijing style which does not use a base, but uses a high gluten flour instead to also make an hand pulled noodle.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IQxVBPo.jpg    - maybe this links works for you

Comment: I haven't found a specific recipe, but after reading a few other discussion boards, lots of people say it's an egg noodle.  You might want to try a few recipes for chinese egg noodles, and see if any of them come close to what you're looking for: https://gingerandscotch.com/homemade-chinese-egg-noodles-from-scratch/ https://www.elmundoeats.com/how-to-make-chinese-egg-noodles/ https://www.diversivore.com/homemade-chinese-egg-noodles/

Answer (score 1):

The picture looks like the 'Hokkien Noodles' you can buy at the supermarket here in Australia. The pack I have is made by Fantastic Snacks. The ingredients are wheat flour, water, wheat gluten, salt, colours (carotene, annnatto, turmeric), and canola oil. They have 6.5g of protein per 100g, 33g carbohydrates (of which 1.8g is dietary fibre), 1.5g fat and 160mg sodium. Maybe that can help you reverse engineer the recipe.